# Upload media only to DB

Tags: images, database, uploads, mysql, media

I'm using the latest WordPress (5.6) and from what I've found out there's no visible setting for uploading media directly to a DB. Is there such an option somewhere hidden or does WordPress not support DB as a media storage instead of `wp-content/uploads`?

I'd like to utilize DB as prioritized (or the only, if possible) storage instead of filesystem and then load the media (such as post images) directly from the DB.

Comment: This is not supported by wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, out of the box WordPress stores images and other uploads only as files.

Although it could be, theoretically, possible to change this behavior by tapping inton [`wp_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/) or [`_wp_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/) and related functions, I think it would be too complex and unreliable. Besides,I think it wouldn't be a good idea for performance reasons in case with too many images (then again, I am not a DB specialist)

And just for good measure, if you want to change uploads folder location, you can do it by defining the `UPLOADS` constant in wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'new-folder-for-uploads' );
```

### Edit 1

Adding my response to the Peter Badida comment about :

I can't tell for sure, but I think you could experiment with the `filesystem_method_file` filter on the WP_Filesystem function, located at line 1867 of /wp-admin/includes/file.php and add your own abstractions.

Bear in mind that plugins and themes will probably use functions, actions and [filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/) that rely on a disk based filesystem. So you will need to keep a lot of the current filesystem for compatibility and make things more complex than needed. Great intelectual and WP developing challenge, but from a pragmatic perspective, I would stick to the default filesystems.

### Edit 2 (from comment)

WordPress is built in a way that you can override or extend a lot of its functionality mostly by using [filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/) and [actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) [hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/). Stick to them and you will have far fewer headaches and imcompatibility issues.

[Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/) you can find all or most of the hooks. Also, you might want to search for `apply_filter` and `do_action`strings on WordPress Core codebase.

Comment: I don't want to use filesystem, so changing a folder isn't a solution for me. However, that `wp_handle_upload()` seems to be workable. Is there some kind of global include file/location where I can put my version of it (with DB insert) so WP uses my `wp_handle_upload()` instead of its? Also, is there another func paired with this for file **retrieval** that would be called in each post and gallery so I can override that as well?

Comment: I see what you mean. I can't tell you for sure, but think you could experiment the `filesystem_method_file` filter on the WP_Filesystem function, located at line 1867 of /wp-admin/includes/file.php and add your own abstractions. But bear in mind that plugins and themes will probably use functions, actions and filters that rely on a disk based filesystem. So you will need to keep a lot of the current filesystem for compatibility and make things more complex than needes. Great intelectual and WP developing challenge, but from a pragmatic perspective, I would stick to the default filesystems.

Comment: Works for me, I'll take a look. Thank you and accepted! :)

Comment: Please, do not forget to share with the community your findings.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to globally override a function in WP via some include/config file or is there at least a single file that is added the last so I can use PHP's `function_exists()` to override it safely? Or is the only way to create a patch and hope it doesn't bork along the way?

Comment: WordPress is built to be overridden mostly by  [filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/) and [actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) [hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/). Stick to them and you will have far fewer headaches and imcompatibility issues. [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/) you can find all or most of them. Also, you might want to search for apply_filter and do_action on WordPress Core codebase.